# Remove MIME description from mutt pager

Tags: mutt, mime-types

Like described [here](http://soc.if.usp.br/manual/mutt/html/manual.html#mime-pager), mutt displays an indicator in the message pager for the attachments displayed, for example:

```
[-- Attachment #1: Description --]
[-- Type: text/plain, Encoding: 7bit, Size: 10000 --]
```

I would like to not display those indicators, just view the content. Is ist possible to disable them in (neo)mutt?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set a display filter to remove those lines:

```
set display_filter = "grep -v -- '^\[-- .* --\]$'"
```

This will remove all lines matching `^\[-- .* --\]$` from your displayed message.